# Is there a utility toolkit for OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

Writing simple OpenCL kernels evolves repeating the following steps:

```
  1.  Put the kernel code in a string
  2.  call clCreateProgramWithSource
  3.  call clBuildProgram
  4.  call clCreateKernel
  5.  call clSetKernelArg (x number of arguments)
  6.  call clEnqueueNDRangeKernel
```

Is there a utility library that can make this process less painful, even in the cost of reduced flexibility? I am looking for something similar to GLUT / OpenGL for writing OpenCL programs

Comment: If you are using C++, I can recommend the official Khronos C++ Wrapper http://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP. Although the parts you are mentioning are still pretty heavy.
If you are looking for a general higher level of abstraction, I can recommend SYCL https://www.khronos.org/registry/SYCL/, which is still using OpenCL under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Intel(R) SDK for OpenCL Applications https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl - it has tools to simplify OpenCL development quite a bit.